# How to get All thread ids and names of a process

Tags: multithreading

I wrote a program using c# that list all running process in window, i want to list all running process in window, and in each process, i want to list all running thread (both name and id). i can't find any function on Window Api to list thread name, how can i do it ?

Example: plz look at this picture:
lh4.googleusercontent.com/HwP6dpts5uRPJIElH7DgUd3x95aQKO36tynkfsaDMBbM=w607-h553-no

in the image, i want to list

- FireFox ID: 123
- Google Chorme ID 456
- ...
- Explorer ID 789
- **Documents ID 654**
- **Temp ID 231**
- ...

Thankyou !

Comment: What programming language? What have you tried? What's your actual problem? Downvoting!

Comment: i'm using c#. i want to list all running process in window, and in each process, i want to list all running thread (name and id).

Comment: You should add matching keywords c# and windows. In general,  don't think your question is very well posed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Systems.Diagnostic namespace and then use:

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach(Process theprocess in processlist){
Console.WriteLine(“Process: {0} ID: {1}”, theprocess.ProcessName, theprocess.Id);
}
```

[Source](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/get-a-list-of-running-processes-in-c/)

[More info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9(v=vs.110).aspx)